# String Switch in Common Lisp

Tags: switch-statement, common-lisp

How do I do a conditional dispatch on a string in Common Lisp?  I'm looking for something like:

```
(case str
        ("a"       "found an a")
        ("abc"     "found an abc")
        (otherwise "other"))
```

so (case "a") returns "found an a"

Answer (score 12):

Alexandria has the macros `switch`, `cswitch`, `eswitch`:

```
(switch (str :test #'equal)
  ("a" "found an a")
  ("abc" "found an abc")
  (t "other"))
```

Answer (score 6):

The [string-case](http://pvk.ca/Blog/Lisp/string_case_bis.html) library implements this functionality. It is available from quicklisp.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial (and potentially slow) variant would be something like:

```
(defmacro string-case (str &rest forms)
  (let* ((strval (gensym "STRVAL"))
         (cond-body (loop for (s . f) in forms 
                          collect `((string= ,strval ,s) ,@f))))
    `(let ((,strval ,str)) (cond ,@cond-body))))
```

This (unfortunately) does not allow for an `else`, `otherwise` or grouping of strings, but making that extension should be pretty straight-forward. Using the existing string-case from quicklisp is probably the better choice.

Comment: Thanks! I used a modified version of this bare-bones example for a Lisp variant that's *almost* CL-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `cond` instead of case.

```
(let ((word "foo"))
  (cond
    ((string= "bar" word) :bar)
    ((string= "foo" word) :foo)
    ((string= "baz" word) :baz)
    (t :unknown)))
```

If strings come from the outside, you might want a "default" case anyway. If the list of strings is really long, you should optimize and then neither `case` nor `cond` will be your weapon of choice. If you want to obfuscate (pretty-up), you could hide the repetitive code behind a macro.

For example:

```
(defmacro string-case (word &body cases)
  `(cond
    ,@(loop 
         for c in cases
         collecting 
         `((string= ,word ,(first c)) ,@(rest c)))))
```

With that macro, the expression would then neatly look like:

```
CL-USER> (string-case "foo"
           ("bar" :bar)
           ("baz" :baz)
           ("foo" :foo)
           (t :unknown))
:FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Practical Common LISP by Seibel only changes made are using the read-char instead of read-line. This worked for me using simple characters "A" "B" etc. To see what the characters and strings actually are try using (format nil "~:C" c) c being character and (format nil "~:S" s) s being string.

```
(defun prompt-read(prompt)
    (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (read-char *query-io*))
(defun move()
  (case(prompt-read "ROW[A-C]")
    (#\A (print "A"))
    (#\B (print "B"))
    (#\C (print "C"))))
```

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get it working by converting the string to a symbol:

```
(case (intern (string-upcase str))
    (a         "found an a")
    (abc       "found an abc")
    (otherwise "other"))
```

Comment: a typical source of problems: you better tell `INTERN` which package it should use - otherwise it would use the runtime value of `*package*`.

Comment: Even so, for arbitrary input `str` values, you'll keep **every** distinct interned symbol for the lifetime of the running process, in essence, a memory leak.